# Issue Using PrintDocument in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF file in PowerShell to another PDF (to remove some properties), using this [earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785842/print-a-pdf-to-a-file-in-powershell). It's essentially the same code I'm using, but I'm adding 'Microsoft Print to PDF' as the printer. It doesn't throw any errors, but it seems to just generate a blank pdf.

```
$PrintDocument = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
$PrintDocument.DocumentName = "c:\temp\fileToOpen.pdf"
$printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = $true
$PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
$printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "c:\temp\newFile.pdf" #this is the blank file 
$PrintDocument.Print()
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks so much

Comment: I guess it's no help, but I can reproduce your findings.

Comment: For what it's worth I found a working solution to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65760455/how-to-automate-print-to-pdf-with-windows-powershell

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick, if you'd like to post as the answer.